# How To Force Table Filters To Use Input Boxes?

Tags: oracle-adf

There seems to be a minor bug with the default dropdown filters when you enable filtering, is there a simpler way to force a table to use all input box style filters rather than to implement custom filters for each default drop down.

I think custom filters will solve the issue, but the problem is that doing so for the many tables will probably take far too long.

Answer (score 0):

yes - you get dropdowns for fields where you are adding LOVs to.
But if you will create a duplication of the field (one attribute with LOV, a second  attribute - without), you can show inside the table the-attribute-with-LOV, but in filter you will use the-attribute-without-LOV.

You will need to edit the jsff sources yourself.